# How to add custom style to the radio button?

Tags: html, reactjs, material-ui, react-radio-buttons

I want to know how to add a custom style to the radio button like the screenshot below. It needs to keep the number `No.01` and then the label beside it. Is there any way to do it in react element or HTML element?

If you have any ideas please, I would appreciate a solution.

[image]

Comment: The number use css counter or number declared in the html?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it in CSS file or by using style tag inside the head element and by giving a class to that radio button.

Answer (score 0):

Try this!

```css
input[type="radio"] {
  /* ...existing styles */
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

input[type="radio"]::before {
  content: "";
  color: green;
  width: 1em;
  height: 1em;
  border-radius: 50%;
  transform: scale(.5);
  transition: 120ms transform ease-in-out;
  box-shadow: inset 1em 1em green;
}
```

```html
<html>
<body>
<label>Radio Button</label>
<input type="radio">
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use [`accent-color`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/accent-color) property

```css
.green {
  accent-color: green;
}
```

```html
<h3>group 1</h3>
<input class="green" name="group1" type="radio" />
<input class="green" name="group1" type="radio" checked/>

<h3>group 2</h3>
<input class="green" name="group2" type="radio" checked/>
<input class="green" name="group2" type="radio" checked/>

<h3>group 3</h3>
<input class="green" name="group3" type="radio" />
<input class="green" name="group3" type="radio" />
```

If you want to use css counter to show number

```css
.green {
  --size: 16px;
  width: var(--size);
  height: var(--size);
  accent-color: green;
  counter-increment: radioGreen;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
}

.green::after {
  margin-left: calc(var(--size) * 1.2);
  content: "No." counter(radioGreen, decimal-leading-zero);
}

.radio-group {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
  counter-reset: radioGreen;
}
```

```html
<div class="radio-group">
  <h3>Group 1</h3>
  <input class="green" name="group1" type="radio" />
  <input class="green" name="group1" type="radio" />
  <input class="green" name="group1" type="radio" />
</div>
<div class="radio-group">
  <h3>Group 2</h3>
  <input class="green" name="group2" type="radio" />
  <input class="green" name="group2" type="radio" />
  <input class="green" name="group2" type="radio" />
</div>
```